# MUI with django framework

Tags: django, material-ui, server-side

Is it possible to use mui with a django framework? I would like to keep it server-side using django. I know typically mui is built with client side rendering by using a react library. I did find a cdn library in muicss.com but i'm afraid this library is outdated. I would like to use the current version 5.0 and all of it's classes/components. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an official CDN version of MUI which will help you build HTML web components using Server-Side Rendering.

- [Material Components for the web](https://material.io/develop/web)
- [Getting Started](https://material.io/develop/web/getting-started)
- [MDC-101 Web:Material Components (MDC) Basics (Web)](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-web#0)
- [Github repo](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web)

You can benefit from this by adding the CSS & JS "CDN versions" into a regular HTML template, for example the below "home.html" and then render it using Django views; You can for sure pass context variables, and all what Django can offer while rendering the template.

Example `home.html`:

```
!-- Required styles for Material Web -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
<h1>Hello {{ dummy_context }}</h1> <!-- Render Django Context -->
<!-- Render textfield component -->
<label class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--filled">
  <span class="mdc-text-field__ripple"></span>
  <span class="mdc-floating-label" id="my-label">Label</span>
  <input type="text" class="mdc-text-field__input" aria-labelledby="my-label">
  <span class="mdc-line-ripple"></span>
</label>

<!-- Required Material Web JavaScript library -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
<!-- Instantiate single textfield component rendered in the document -->
<script>
  mdc.textField.MDCTextField.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field'));
</script>
```

`views.py`:

```py
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

class HomePageView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['dummy_context'] = "This is a dummy context"
        return context
```

`urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path

from myapp.views import HomePageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

There's a complete list of the available MUI packages/components in the [Github repo](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages).